# Custom Button as a Navigation Button

Tags: ios, keyboard, uinavigationbar

I have a custom button like facebook app does. When I click on custom button while editing my textview, it shows left menu but doesn't hide keyboard.

I have tried everything but still my problem is there. How I can hide keyboard on clicking on custom button.

Comment: setDelegate for textView, then resignFirstResponder

Answer (score 0):

Just include this in the burger's button `IBAction`

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```